# Change Pre-commit Ids

Tags: git, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am checking my commits and pre-commit Ids for validation. I am using the following command to get the list

> `git log -10 --no-merges master | Select-String -Pattern "commit"`

And I found Last commit message missed the pre-commit

[image]

Is there any way to correct (Add missing pre-commits)? much appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

If it is the last commit, you can simply:

- run your pre-commit to check/get the ID
- amend the last commit message ([`git commit --amend`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---amend)) with that checked ID
- and force push (`git push --force`).

Make sure to notify your collaborators on the project, for them to update their `origin/master` whose last commit would have changed ID.